# Cooking different meats on George Foreman grill

Tags: food-safety, chicken, cleaning, grilling, steak

If I cook some chicken breasts on a George Foreman Grill, can I cook another type of meat straight after it? Or do I need to clean the grill inbetween each?

I've been doing the latter since I bought once recently as I didn't want to take any chances, but it is proving a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be OK as long as the grill stays hot.

IT is a bit like if you would pan fry some chicken and after that add a steak to the pan.